# Java method not evaluated in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, binary-tree, evaluation

I am studying binary tree in Java, and for some reason, it does not call both methods in the if () evaluation below:

```
if (method1() && method2())
```

I believe this should evaluate both method1 & method2. However, my code is calling only method1.

Below is my entire code. I am looking at `printPaths(Node node, String str)` method.

```
public class Tree {
    private static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node (int newData) {
            data = newData;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    Tree () {
        root = null;
    }

    public void insert (int newData) {
        root = insert(root, newData);
    }

    private Node insert (Node node, int newData) {
        if (node == null)
            node = new Node (newData);
        else if (newData < node.data)
            node.left = insert (node.left, newData);
        else // if (newData >= node.data)
            node.right = insert (node.right, newData);
        return node;
    }


    public void printPaths () {
        printPaths (root, "");
    }

    private boolean printPaths (Node node, String str) {
        if (node == null)
            return true;
        else {
            str += String.valueOf(node.data) + " ";
            if (printPaths(node.left, str) && printPaths(node.right, str))
                System.out.println(str);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(2);
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(5);
        tree.printPaths();
    }
}
```

The output of this program is simply

```
3 2 1
```

where I think it should output

```
3 2 1
3 4 5
```

If I were to replace the `printPaths(Node node, String str)` method with the following

```
private boolean printPaths (Node node, String str) {
    if (node == null)
        return true;
    else {
        str += String.valueOf(node.data) + " ";
        boolean a, b;
        a = printPaths(node.left, str);
        b = printPaths(node.right, str);
        if (a && b)
            System.out.println(str);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The output becomes correct; that is

```
3 2 1
3 4 5
```

Could someone please explain why so?

Comment: `&&` is short circuiting. The right operand is evaluated only if the left operand is true.

Answer (score 3):

> I believe this should evaluate both method1 & method2. However, my code is calling only method1.

No, `method1() && method2()` doesn't call `method2` if `method1` returned false. If you want both methods to always be invoked you can use `&`. Use of `&` is so rare, that you should probably write a comment to indicate that it's deliberate.

```
// Use of & is intentional, not a typo.
if (method1() & method2())
```

Comment: No problem, `||` and `?:` are also lazy in this way, only evaluating what they need.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator in `Java` is a ["Short-Circuting" operator](http://users.drew.edu/bburd/JavaForDummies4/ShortCircuitEval.pdf). With the `&&` operator, both conditions must be `true` in order for overall evaluation to result in `true`. Because of this, `Java` will save execution time by not running the second portion of an `&&` equation if the first portion results in `false`. This is because `false && [anything]` will always result in `false`, so there is no need to check what the second portion is.